# "market- and technology-based"

Tags: suspended-hyphen

Many I ask if it is grammatically correct to put more than one noun in a compound adjective, e.g.,

"market-and technology-based", "market-and technology-driven"..etc?

Many thanks!

Comment: [*ontological foundations derived from a realist philosophy of science provide a more granular understanding of how **“nuts and bolts” based** research can be used.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22nuts+and+bolts+based+research%22) Since *your* "compound adjectival noun adjunct" isn't even an established collocation with a known specific meaning, I'd follow that example (complete with "scare quotes", but without hyphens).

Comment: Why would you use hyphens at all here?

Comment: Many thanks,  FumbleFingers,  tchrist and lbf! So we can have two nouns in a compound adj, but the hyphens need to be removed. But what if the style guide of the company requires it to have a hyphen between the words in the compound? E.g., it needs to be "technology-driven" instead of "technology driven"?

Comment: @Jane In general, always follow whatever your company's style guide says. Hyphenation is subjective, and differs from one company to another. There may be common guidelines, but your company determines what it wants to use. I will add that (barring your company's style guide) if you are combining *market-based* and *technology-based* then the use of a [suspended hyphen](http://editingandwritingservices.com/suspended-hyphens/) is common: *market- and technology-based*.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion from *[Engineering and Managing Software Requirements](https://books.google.com/books?id=JRWrGLuWpLsC&lpg=PA218&ots=mzVR1iymwc&dq=%22market-and%20technology%20driven%22%20in%20a%20sentence&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=%22market-and%20technology%20driven%22%20in%20a%20sentence&f=false)*

> An increasing number of market and technology driven software
>   development companies face the ...